How to set a daily task in an hourly DAG in Airflow?
I have an hourly scheduled DAG in Airflow, the Graph may look like this:
A >> B >> C

The task A and B need to be executed every hour, but task C just needs to be executed once each day. Can I achieve this in Airflow?

Don't use the same DAG if schedules are different.

Please take a look at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html
Your case is about

Two DAGs may have different schedules. E.g. a weekly DAG may have tasks that depend on other tasks on a daily DAG.

